# How to prove this problem about 'the limit under the integral sign'?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> problem:let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of nonnegative measurable function on $\Bbb R$ that converges pointwise on $\Bbb R$ to $f$ and $f$ be integrable over $\Bbb R$,show that:
> If $\int_ \Bbb R f=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_ \Bbb R f_n $,then $\int_E f=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_E f_n $ for any measurable set $E$.

I want to use formula :$\int_E f=\int_ \Bbb R f \mathcal X_E$,but i don't know how to use the condition "$\int_ \Bbb R f=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_ \Bbb R f_n $ "

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma

Comment: $|\int_E f_n-\int_E f| \leq \int |f_n -f| \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks, I read your link.But I haven't studied measure theory.

Comment: But this is a measure theory question.....

Comment: no，this problem comes from Royden Real Analysis part 1 on page 84

Comment: You say it is not measure theory, accepted. Now, what is the material in the chapter/section , for which this question is a part of the exercises? If you don't want people using measure theory, which most would do, you have to then tell them what kind of proof (which tools/theorems) are acceptable.

Comment: OK,thanks your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> lemma:let${x_n}$ and ${y_n}$ be sequence,${x_n}$ is converges,then we have:$\lim inf (x_n+y_n)$=$\lim x_n$ +$\lim inf y_n$.

Proof:we can see $f_n\mathcal X_E $ converges to $f\mathcal X_E$.by fatou's lemma :we have $\int_\Bbb R (f-f\mathcal X_E) ≤ \lim inf\int_\Bbb R (f_n-f_n\mathcal X_E)$
By lemma: we have$\lim inf\int_\Bbb R (f_n-f_n\mathcal X_E)$=$\int_\Bbb R f -\lim supf_n\mathcal X_E$,then we have
$\int_\Bbb R f\mathcal X_E≥\lim sup\int _\Bbb Rf_n\mathcal X_E$.
By fatou's lemma,we have
$\int_E f≤\lim inf \int_E f_n$.
As we desired.